# d3.js tool tip on a force directed graph not displaying complete data while hovering over links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is the **JSON data**:

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([
  ["C2", "ID2", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 2],
  ["C2", "ID2", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 700.0, 3],
  ["C2", "C3", "Customer", "Customer", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 2],
  ["C2", "C3", "Customer", "Customer", "2015-1-2", "2015-1-3", 600.0, 2],
  ["C6", "C1", "Customer", "Customer", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 1],
  ["C5", "ID4", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 2],
  ["C1", "ID1", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 1],
  ["C1", "P1", "Customer", "Phone", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 1],
  ["C6", "P2", "Customer", "Phone", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 2],
  ["C6", "P2", "Customer", "Phone", "2015-1-3", "2015-1-4", 800.0, 2],

  ["C2", "C6", "Customer", "Customer", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 1],
  ["C4", "C3", "Customer", "Customer", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 3],
  ["C1", "C2", "Customer", "Customer", '2015-1-1', "2015-1-1", 500.0, 1],
  ["C4", "ID3", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 3],
  ["C3", "ID3", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 3],
  ["C1", "C5", "Customer", "Customer", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 1]
]);
```

I am iterating through this JSON data to turn it into a format suitable for making the graph as follows:

```
         var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
var startnodes = [];
var endnodes = [];
var startnodetype = [];
var endnodetype = [];
var SendTime = [];
var PayTime = [];
var Total_Amt = [];
var Depth = [];
galData.map(function(e, i) {
  startnodes.push(e[0]);
  endnodes.push(e[1]);
  startnodetype.push(e[2]);
  endnodetype.push(e[3]);
  SendTime.push(e[4]);
  PayTime.push(e[5]);
  Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
  Depth.push(e[7]);
});
var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth);
makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);
```

The **createNodes ()** function is below:

```
            function createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, SendTime, PayTime, Total_Amt, Depth) {
  var node_set = [];
  var links = [];
  var nodetype = d3.set();
  startnodes.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt = endnodes[i];
    if (!node_set.find(function(d) {
        return d.id == src
      })) {
      node_set.push({
        id: src,
        type: startnodetype[i]
      });
    }
    if (!node_set.find(function(d) {
        return d.id == tgt
      })) {
      node_set.push({
        id: tgt,
        type: endnodetype[i]
      });
    }

    links.push({
      source: src,
      target: tgt,
      sendtime: SendTime[i],
      paytime: PayTime[i],
      total_amt: Total_Amt[i],
      depth: Depth[i],
      value: 1
    });
  });

  startnodetype.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt_type = endnodetype[i];
    nodetype.add(src);
    nodetype.add(tgt_type);
  });

  var d3GraphData = {
    nodes: node_set.map(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        type: d.type,
        group: 1
      }
    }),
    links: links,
    nodetype: nodetype.values().map(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        group: 1
      }
    })
  }
  return d3GraphData;

};
```

In my **makeGraph() function** I am able to display the text while hovering through nodes and links using a tooltip:

I display

```
   nodes: d.id and d.type,
   links: d.paytime,d.Sendtime,d.Amount and d.depth
```

Below is the code:

```
     var tooltip = d3.select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);


       var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3GraphData.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", .8);
      tooltip.html("<p/>Paytime:" + d.paytime + "<p/>Amount:" + d.total_amt + "<p/>SendTime:" + d.sendtime + "<p/>Depth" + d.depth)

      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    });

  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3GraphData.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.type);
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", .8);
      tooltip.html(d.id + "<p/>type:" + d.type)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
```

This code works fine and does display the text on hovering over links.

But considering this scenario:

```
["C2", "ID2", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-1", "2015-1-1", 500.0, 2],
   ["C2", "ID2", "Customer", "ID_Card", "2015-1-2", "2015-1-3", 700.0, 2]
```

Here Nodes "C2" and "ID2" have 2 interactions between them , but on hovering over the links the tooltip shows the following:

```
  PayTime: 2015-1-3
  Amount: 700
  SendTime: 2015-1-2
  Depth: 3
```

Ideally I want it to  display something like this: So that the data for both the interactions between them is captured.

```
  PayTime: 2015-1-3
  Amount: 700
  SendTime: 2015-1-2
  Depth: 3

   PayTime: 2015-1-1
  Amount: 500
  SendTime: 2015-1-1
  Depth: 2
```

Below is the link for the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/37xuxpsz/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect your force chart you're gonna see that, for that particular link you mentioned (C2 to ID2), you have **two** lines. When you mouse over the link, you get only the information regarding the **top** line (the one that fires the mouseover).

There is a solution for this. Inside the mouseover (or mousemove, it doesn't matter), create a function that gets *all* the data regarding those two nodes (source and target). This is the function:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
            var thisSource = d.source.id,
                thisTarget = d.target.id;
            var filteredLinks = d3GraphData.links.filter(function(e) {
                return (e.source.id === thisSource && e.target.id === thisTarget) 
                    || (e.source.id === thisTarget && e.target.id === thisSource);
            });
```

This function creates a new array, named `filteredLinks`, with all the data you need. For instance, if you hover over that link you mentioned, you get this as the result:

```
[{
    "source": {
        "id": "C2",
        "type": "Customer",
        "group": 1,
        "index": 0,
        "x": 405.82425848083665,
        "y": 335.62277280058106,
        "vy": -0.0002356554712780902,
        "vx": 0.00011724088097396833
    },
    "target": {
        "id": "ID2",
        "type": "ID_Card",
        "group": 1,
        "index": 1,
        "x": 387.34926064098437,
        "y": 307.0409186320801,
        "vy": -0.000681439057517941,
        "vx": 0.0008168234236215556
    },
    "sendtime": "2015-1-1",
    "paytime": "2015-1-1",
    "total_amt": 500,
    "depth": 2,
    "value": 1,
    "index": 0
}, {
    "source": {
        "id": "C2",
        "type": "Customer",
        "group": 1,
        "index": 0,
        "x": 405.82425848083665,
        "y": 335.62277280058106,
        "vy": -0.0002356554712780902,
        "vx": 0.00011724088097396833
    },
    "target": {
        "id": "ID2",
        "type": "ID_Card",
        "group": 1,
        "index": 1,
        "x": 387.34926064098437,
        "y": 307.0409186320801,
        "vy": -0.000681439057517941,
        "vx": 0.0008168234236215556
    },
    "sendtime": "2015-1-2",
    "paytime": "2015-1-3",
    "total_amt": 700,
    "depth": 3,
    "value": 1,
    "index": 1
}]
```

Now, just use that filtered array to populate your tooltip. As this is **a lot** of work, I'll leave that part to you...

PS: The best solution, however, is *not* having two overlapping lines at the first place. To deal with that, you could search for duplicates in your links array and merge them, before painting the chart.

Comment: great solution. How did you find out that there were two lines? ALso , I am kinda new to javascript/d3 so having a hard time populating that tooltip from the array...

Comment: It's easy: if you have two objects, you have two lines (but you always can inspect the DOM). Regarding populating the tooltip, as this is a different problem, please post another question.